# dj_static import error in django application to be uploaded on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

In Heroku, I upload my Django application, and it works well with the following code in `wsgi.py`:

```
from django.core.wsgi
import get_wsgi_application
#from dj_static import Cling

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "hellodjango.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
#application = Cling(get_wsgi_application()
```

But when I uncomment the commented lines my application crashes in Heroku.

Also when I import dj_static in the Python interpreter I get the following error:

```
>>> from dj_static import Cling 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dj_static-0.0.6-py2.7.egg/dj_static.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler as DebugHandler
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/views.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.views import static
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/static.py", line 98, in <module>
    template_translatable = ugettext_noop("Index of %(directory)s")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 60, in gettext_noop
    return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 47, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Why it this happening? Just by importing dj_static these errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install dj-static file.
* Check this https://www.versioneye.com/python/dj-static/0.0.6